# Нужна ли здесь запятая?(,)

Tags: пунктуация

Этот феномен происходит как вследствие усиленной работы почек при повышенном давлении, а так же как приспособительная реакция организма(,) направленная на уменьшение объема циркулирующей крови и, следовательно, снижения артериального давления.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая однозначно нужна, так как мы обособляем причастный оборот после определяемого слова. Кроме того, желательно отредактировать текст в части употребления союзов (предлагается два варианта):

(1)Этот феномен происходит вследствие усиленной работы почек при повышенном давлении, **а также** является приспособительной реакцией организма, направленной на уменьшение объема циркулирующей крови и, следовательно, снижение артериального давления.

(2)Этот феномен происходит вследствие **как**  усиленной работы почек при повышенном давлении, **так и** приспособительной реакции организма, направленной на уменьшение объема циркулирующей крови и, следовательно, снижение артериального давления.

Comment: Спасибо... Глупые копирайтеры совсем не умеют писать.